# spring-kafka error handler invoked too many times

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using spring's `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` with `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`.
A message is logged each time the error handler is called, and also an event is being sent to our monitoring system.
The issue I'm seeing is that the error handler is invoked too many times for consecutive records causing a failure.
For example, for a non-retryable exception, if I produce 2 (error) msgs I get the following logs:

```
|ERROR|Y|147e885e-9cce-4d10-972f-96613757c511|2020-10-22 13:55:41  [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1] Kafka:65|orgTest|projectTest|dev|input| my error log
|ERROR|Y|147e885e-9cce-4d10-972f-96613757c511|2020-10-22 13:55:41  [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1] Kafka:65|orgTest|projectTest|dev|input| <== my error log
|INFO|Y|147e885e-9cce-4d10-972f-96613757c511|2020-10-22 13:55:41  [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.KafkaConsumer:1603|orgTest|projectTest|dev|input| [Consumer clientId=consumer-debug-2, groupId=debug] Seeking to offset 5 for partition debug-2
DEBUG|||2020-10-22 13:55:42  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] o.s.k.l.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer:296||||| Successful dead-letter publication
|ERROR|Y|f0ecbdfa-3a13-4435-9cd1-b3daf73d324d|2020-10-22 13:55:42  [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1] Kafka:65|orgTest|projectTest|dev|input| my error logs
DEBUG|||2020-10-22 13:55:42  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] o.s.k.l.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer:296||||| Successful dead-letter publication
```

It seems like for x consumer error msgs I get: x calls to the error handler, x-1 calls to the error handler, x-2 calls, etc.

The same goes for a retriable exception, for which I see the same for each retry.
The Consumer function is invoked correctly, it's only the error handler that is triggered too many times.

This is my error handling configuration:

```java
public class CustomSeekToCurrentErrorHandler extends SeekToCurrentErrorHandler {
    private final Monitor monitor;

    CustomSeekToCurrentErrorHandler(Monitor monitor, DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer dlpr, FixedBackOff retries) {
        super(dlpr, retries);
        super.setLogLevel(KafkaException.Level.DEBUG);
        this.monitor = monitor;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(Exception exception, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container) {
        if (!records.isEmpty()) {
            records.forEach(record -> {
                logAndReportError(record);
            });
        }
        super.handle(exception, records, consumer, container);
    }
}

@Bean
public SeekToCurrentErrorHandler replayDeadLetterErrorHandler(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer dlpr, FixedBackOff fxboff) {
    var seekToCurrent = new CustomSeekToCurrentErrorHandler(monitor, dlpr, fxboff);
   seekToCurrent.addNotRetryableException(SomeFatalException.class);
   return seekToCurrent;
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Why is the error handler triggered so many times?
2. Why does a seek is being executed for non-retriable exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your question is not clear; please add your code and configuration.
2. We have to seek the records after the failed one so that they are redelivered on the next poll.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added my error handler config in the original question.
I might have some misunderstanding of how the error handler operates.
Let's say consumer polls 500 msgs, and 10 of them fail, will each failure cause a seek and immediate re-polling?
When I'm sending 3 msgs, all of them causing a fatal error (non-retryable), I expect to see 3 error logs, instead, I see 3 error logs, seek, 2 error logs, seek, 1 error log, seek, dead letter publish

Comment: Yes; that is expected - it's because you are logging the remaining records each time, as well as the one that failed. When a record fails, that record (and any remaining that have not yet been processed) are passed to the error handler so the seeks can be performed. When retries are exhausted, or the exception is not retryable, we don't seek the first record (unless the recovery fails). The mistake you are making is you are logging all the records, not just the one that failed. But, you should be seeing a  publish for each failed record, not just the last one.

Comment: Yes, im seeing a publish for each one, sorry.
Is there a way of telling which record has caused the failure? is that the first one in the list?

Comment: It's always the first record in the list. If 500 records are polled and the 10th fails, you will get 491 records (with the failed record at position 0 in the list).

Comment: See the javadocs for `RemainingRecordsErrorHandler`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gary!